# Data type of attributes in igraph, python

Tags: python, cython, igraph, dynamic-data, static-data

In order to speed up my code, I am using Cython. I was wondering whether it is possible to fix the type of attributes for a Graph object in igraph?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in igraph are returning `PyObject`s so no, you cannot type them in Cython.

However, depending on your use case, it may be useful to pre-assign the attributes to a typed c++ vector or a C array, then work on this vector/array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am a little confused, how pre-assign can help? isn't it the case that each time you call the attributes, python should go and check the type of attributes?

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to use them several times, you can store them first in a typed container (though that will have a more significant impact on your memory consumption)